# Merge sublists that contain the same LAST string in Python 3

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have created a list of lists (call it AllRecipes) with strings:

```
   >>> AllRecipes [['Tomato', 'hot', 'Pasta'], ['Mushrooms', 'Lettuce', 'cold', 'Salad'], ['Chocolate', 'Nuts', 'hot', 'Cookies'], ['Vegetables', 'Lemon', 'cold', 'Pasta'], ['Chocolate', 'Pistachio', 'hot', 'Cookies'], ['Cheese', 'hot', 'Pasta'], ['Lettuce', 'Fruits', 'cold', 'Salad']]
```

I want to combine sublists that contain the same LAST string as such:
1) Take for i in range(len(AllRecipes)):

```
AllRecipes[i][-1] == 'Pasta':
AllRecipes[0] = ['Tomato', 'hot', 'Pasta']
AllRecipes[3] = ['Vegetables', 'Lemon', 'cold', 'Pasta']
AllRecipes[5] = ['Cheese', 'hot', 'Pasta']
```

2) Turn it into:

```
Pasta = { hot: ['Tomato'], hot: ['Cheese'], cold: ['Vegetables', 'Lemon']}
```

Please let me know if my question is not clear. Thank you in advance for your help :)

Follow up question (now that I have the dictionaries made for each):

Say I have a list ToCook = [] where ToCook = ['Pasta', 'Cookies', 'Salad'] 
How can I retrieve, for each item in ToCook, its equivalent dictionary?

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid structure. Are you trying to make it a dictionary? Should those commas actually be colons? Also, have you tried to do this yet? Can you show your own code?

Comment: the last construct is not a valid Python object.

Comment: Even on second inspection, something else is not right with your expected output. Please confirm what it is you are exactly looking for by producing a valid Python output.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake, a Dictionary of lists, so yes I meant : not ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably easiest to solve with a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

AllRecipes=[['Tomato', 'hot', 'Pasta'], ['Mushrooms', 'Lettuce', 'cold', 'Salad'], ['Chocolate', 'Nuts', 'hot', 'Cookies'], ['Vegetables', 'Lemon', 'cold', 'Pasta'], ['Chocolate', 'Pistachio', 'hot', 'Cookies'], ['Cheese', 'hot', 'Pasta'], ['Lettuce', 'Fruits', 'cold', 'Salad']]

mydict = defaultdict(list)

for recipe in AllRecipes:
    mydict[recipe[-1]].append(recipe[:-1])

for key, vals in mydict.items():
    print('{} : {}'.format(key,vals))
```

this results in

```
Pasta : [['Tomato', 'hot'], ['Vegetables', 'Lemon', 'cold'], ['Cheese', 'hot']]
Cookies : [['Chocolate', 'Nuts', 'hot'], ['Chocolate', 'Pistachio', 'hot']]
Salad : [['Mushrooms', 'Lettuce', 'cold'], ['Lettuce', 'Fruits', 'cold']]
```

Comment: How would I be able to do the following now: say I have a list ToCook = [] where ToCook = ['Pasta', 'Cookies', 'Salad'] how can I retrieve for each item in ToCook, its equivalent dictionary?

Comment: Just how you do it with a normal dictionary. `mydict['Pasta']` for instance will give you all pasta recipes. Have a look at the last two lines of the example given.

Comment: Thank you! As you will have noticed I am very new to this.